# Are the user control context and http context the same in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext

I have a user control in my ASP.NET application. Does the [Control.Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.context(v=vs.110).aspx) object in the user control and the global [HttpContext.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) point to the same object? Can I use one in lie of other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all accessors that return `HttpContext` (pages, controls, controllers,...) return exactly the same object that set for current request - same as `HttpContext.Current` returns.